# Sending personal message using MGTwitterEngine in iOS

Tags: ios, mgtwitterengine

Does MGTwitterEngine provides sending personal message to a selected person in Twitter. Or is there any possibility for sending tweet to a selected person only.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I dont know much about mgtwitter engine except that i had to drop it from my project because it dint allow me to upload images but going through the documentation i could find this

```
- (NSString *)sendDirectMessage:(NSString *)message to:(NSString *)username; // direct_messages/new
```

Comment: Thank you Aatish. I will check and let you know. Are you sure that it doesn't allow to upload images?

Comment: not from what i have read .. i had to change to GSTwitPicEngine https://github.com/Gurpartap/GSTwitPicEngine

Comment: That means for sending pic to twitter, do we need to use GSTwitPicEngine instead of MGTwitterEngine? Thanks.

Comment: ok Aatish, I would like to one more thing. The authentication procedure of MGTwitterEngine. Do we need any confirmation from Twitter in order to login with different user. ie, Sending a mail to Twitter with Application screens and other info? Now I have did everything as the documentation of MGTwitter engine provides. But I am not able to login to the app. So I just hardcoded the tokens in the project and doing the functionality of projects. Does I am not able to login due to the confirmation of Twitter? or this is an issue with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would have to be more specific .. 
heres the link i used to get me acquainted with the engine ..
http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/

Comment: Dear Aatish, I would like to know the the purpose of"- (NSString *) sendUpdate:(NSString *)status inReplyTo:(NSString *)updateID", class method is used in MGTwitterEngine. Also what is the parameters refers to in this methods. Also I have doubt about the parameter "username" in sendDirectMessage. I have listed followers and followings list. Does the userinfo of followers and followings contains the parameters needed to use in sendDirectMessage and sendUpdate method. I'd like to know what keys in userinfo dictionary contains the values for those parameters. Please help me.Thanks in advance